# How to modify label text in C# forms

Tags: c#, winforms, label

(I am very new to C#) I am creating a forms application, and the purpose is to get a string from a Web API, then put that text onto a label. I have successfully gotten the data from the Web, but when I try to update the label, I have no luck.
I have debugged and found that my method inside my class *Is* executing, but just not setting the label's text. As you can see below, I tried to use `this.resultLabel.text = str;`. Here's the classes:

Program.cs (not the form cs file)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
namespace WebsiteAPITest
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());

        }

    }
    class PostManager
    {
        public void setupClient()
        {


            HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://yakovliam.com/phpApi/csTest.php"));

            WebReq.Method = "GET";

            HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();

            string respStr;
            using (Stream stream = WebResp.GetResponseStream())   //modified from your code since the using statement disposes the stream automatically when done
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                respStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            MessageBox.Show(respStr);
            Form1 form = new Form1();
            form.SetResultLabel(respStr);

        }


    }

}
```

Actual form class (Form1.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WebsiteAPITest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void GetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PostManager postManager = new PostManager();
            postManager.setupClient();
        }
        public void SetResultLabel(string str)
        {
            this.resultLabel.Text = str;
            this.resultLabel.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

proof of label name: [image: Img of label]

Comment: It normally is enough to just set the text. The redraw will happen Automagically. My only guess is that the "resultLabel" is not the label you are looking for? Or maybe you just made it way to small for the text? As a beginner with the designer it can be easy to add or modify the wrong element or set faulty values.

Comment: Where is the call to SetResultLabel? Are there multithread-related issues? Jacob is probably right and you are trying to set the wrong label. Post your Form1.Designer.cs

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I was about to post it anyway before I read your comment. I forgot to mention that I am creating another instance of the class (is it an instance? I work with Python & Java, I call it that) (Form1 form = new Form1();).

Comment: I am pretty sure I'm setting the right label. In my form designer I titled it `resultLabel`. The text is `N/A`, but after the request I am trying to update it to the result. https://imgur.com/a/c2m5amN

Comment: The form being shown to the user in `Application.Run(new Form1());` is not the same as the one you're using in `setupClient` when you do `form.SetResultLabel(respStr);` You should probably have `setupClient` accept a form as a parameter, and then pass in `this` when you call it.

Comment: `Form1 form = new Form1();`  You created a new Form1 that you aren't showing.  You want to reference the one you already have.

Comment: How can I reference the existing form? In my program.cs `Form1` isn't static.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Rufus, you were right. However, Dour High Arc stole your answer :)

Comment: @Jacob Yes the terminology is correct: You create instances of a class. And especially if you got Multiple instances of a GUI Element, it really becomes hard to keep track of them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `setupClient` you call `Form1 form = new Form1()`; that creates a second `Form1` which you never display, then you call `SetResultLabel(respStr)` inside this second form you never display, then you leave the method and discard it.

If you want to call `SetResultLabel` of your calling form, you have to pass the calling form to `setupClient`:

```
public void setupClient(Form1 callingForm)
{
    ...
    callingForm.SetResultLabel(respStr);
```

Then inside your `Form1`:

```
postManager.setupClient(this);
```

It's quite dangerous to pass forms to other methods; a better design is to have the other method return data to your form:

```
public string setupClient()
{
    ...
    return respStr;
}
```

And inside `Form1`:

```
SetResultLabel(postManager.setupClient());
```