# C# Form textbox doesn't refresh when apply value from a Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created a new Windows Form Project in Visual Studio. In this project, I create a new Class to put all my code in it.

In my Form1.cs, I call my Class like this:

```
 MyNewClass mnc = new MyNewClass();
```

In my button code, I put something like this:

```
 mnc.MyMethods();
```

In my class, I call my form like this:

```
 Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

In my methods, I made this code:

```
 form1.MyTextBox.Text = "Salut toi";
 form1.Refresh();
```

But nothing appears in my form.

Comment: You already declared From?

Comment: `Form1 form1 = new Form1();`  This is most likely not the form you see on the screen.  It's "new", and not "shown".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify label text in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57299733/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You instantiate `MyNewClass` in `Form1`, but in `MyMethods()` you create a new instance of `MyNewClass` and try to update the values the new instance.
One solution is to pass a reference of `Form1` to `MyMethods()` like this:

```
public void MyMethods(Form1 form1)
{
 form1.MyTextBox.Text = "Salut toi";
}
```

And then in your `Form1.cs`, you write the following code:

```
 MyNewClass mnc = new MyNewClass();
 mnc.MyMethods(this);
```

You only have to make sure, that `MyTextBox` is not `private`. You can make it `public` by changing that in `Form1.Designer.cs` or using the designer and changing the property `Modifiers` to `public`.

Comment: Thank you soooo much man !! I tried so solve it during a long time !

Answer (score 0):

The methods in MyClass are creating a new Form1 and using it. They are not interacting with the instance of Form1 that is being shown on the sceen.

Here's a (not so great) text diagram of the information flow.

Form1 formOnScreen - - - >MyClass myClass - - - > Form1 newForm

What you want is for MyClass to call methods on the instance of Form1 that is on the screen. To do that, it needs a reference to that Form1. You can give it an instance of Form1 by passing it as a parameter in the methods you call on MyClass, by passing it to the constructor of MyForm and having it store the instance as a field, by creating a property on MyClass and setting it after creating an instance of MyClass, or any number of other ways.